# 'Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token o'

Tags: jquery, json, syntax, local-storage

```
var currentFood = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentFood"));

<some HTML using the currentFood object>

$('#addFood').on("click", function(){
    var allFood = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allFood")) || [];
    allFood.push(currentFood);
    localStorage.setItem("allFood", JSON.stringify(allFood));
});
```

After checking console.log, **currentFood** is returning the correct object, however, the following code is returning an "unexpected token error 0" on the first line of my click event.

Comment: Well, it looks like the value of the `allFood` key in local storage is incorrect/malformed JSON. You might want to set a breakpoint on that first line of your click handler via the developer tools, and then run `localStorage.getItem('allFood')` in the JS console to see the string of JSON stored in there.

Comment: At other question i've readed that it may be coding issue :)
Are you having any weird signs in currentFood?  Or maybe it's too long .

Comment: If the object you're getting from localStorage is simply the string representation of a JS object that *isn't* stored as JSON, this error would likely happen when the JSON parser tried to parse the very first part, `"[object..."` So perhaps we need to see the code that *puts* this value in localStorage to see what's going on.

Comment: Figured it out now, I just needed to clear localStorage in the browser Dev Tools as they were holding incorrect information from previous updates! The code above was perfectly fine. Thanks for suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared localStorage in the browser Dev Tools as they were holding incorrect information from previous updates. My code above was fine.